# I've cloned my VPS content incl. domain into a new VPS with new IP but "Refused to connect to the site webscraping.pro"

Tags: centos, ip, vps

I've cloned my VPS content into a new VPS with new IP ( OS: Centos 7) but
"**Refused to connect to the site webscraping.pro**"
or
"**Refused to connect to the site 178.208.88.6**"

1. The tech support cloned site from old VPS (IP 185.221.154.249) to the new VPS (IP 178.208.88.6).
2. I've changed the IP in interfaces, at the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens18`. Result: http://joxi.ru/8An01XytN7ZWxm
3. Added new IP thru Vesta CP and set the domain name to that IP: http://joxi.ru/823jGOQCzDZZLm
4. Added new IP into the primary DNS NS: http://joxi.ru/bmoOyo7IO9RZkm

**What's wrong**? **How to solve the problem**?

### Update

Today (12.04.2022) the webscraping.pro is working from the old VPS, IP 185.221.154.249.
The domain name has (of subreg.cz registrar) been tied to the old VPS: [image]

Yet all old VPS content is cloned to the new VPS.
Might there be some competition between VPS (new and old ) of where does the domain name refer to ?
Should I change something at the registrar DNS (subreg.cz) ?

### Update 2

I was told to check A record of the domain.
Where is it ?
How can I change it ?

Comment: The "A" record is what is used to point your domain to an IPv4 address, it will be set at the registrar's client area for your domain.
 If you are using custom nameservers then you will need to set them there.

Answer (score 2):

A query using dig utility shows that the DNS 'A' record is still reporting the old address:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
webscraping.pro.        14400   IN      A       185.221.154.249
```

If you have made this change recently, it may not have updated at the primary registrar, yet.
In the meantime, check again on your DNS settings. If they are set properly it may still take several hours for the change to be fully enacted.

As of this edit, your nameservers (NS) are set as:

```
 ns51.ruweb.net
 ns52.ruweb.net
```

So you need to access the records set for that service. There should be an "A" record set there for IP address `185.221.154.249`. Change the address for that record to `178.208.88.6`.

Comment: see my Updates....

Comment: Where you set your other records - TXT - MX - is the same for A record. 
So you would set "Domain": webscraping.pro | "Type": A  | "Value": 178.208.88.6 in your DNS records.